# Placing a .bib file in a package folder - TeXWorks can't find it?

Tags: bibtex, texworks, folders

I have created a `courses.bib` database file for all my course litterature, which I have placed along with a package of mine named `tlnames.sty` that defines some related macros. The folder in which both files reside is `~/documents/texlive/texmf/tex/latex/tlnames`.

I'm compiling this from inside [TeXWorks using a modified version of the LaTeXmk script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34489/223), which works fine except for the bibliography - it can't find `courses.bib`. Finding `tlnames.sty` works OK - I can import the package and use macros from it.

I have, since I placed `courses.bib` there, run `texhash ~/documents/texlive/texmf` and recievd the following output

```
$ texhash texmf
texhash: Updating /home/tomas/documents/texlive/texmf/ls-R... 
texhash: Done.
```

Why is this not working? What do I need to do to help BiBTeX find my database?

For completeness of the question: I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, with TeX Live 2011 and TeXWorks version 0.5 r.952.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Still running 11.10, but....)

I wouldn't put my `.bib` file there.  If you want a system-wide solution, try running this command from the terminal:

```
kpsewhich -var-value BIBINPUTS
```

For me, that gives me a bunch of choices, including

```
~/home/<username>/texmf
```

So if I add a file like `test.bib` to:

```
~/home/<username>/texmf/bibtex/bib/
```

BibTeX and/or Biber can find this file even without using `texhash`.  (This works from within emacs and from a terminal; I don't have TeXWorks.)

Answer (score 5):

Files stored inside the `texmf` tree have to be in the 'correct' locations for TeX to find them. In the case of `.bib` files, they need to be inside `texmf/bibtex/bib`. From your description, `~/documents/texlive/texmf` is a local tree on your system, so you need the `.bib` file inside

```
~/documents/texlive/texmf/bibtex/bib
```

You can further sub-divide things if you wish, so perhaps

```
~/documents/texlive/texmf/bibtex/bib/tlnames
```

would be a location you could use.

Recent TeX Live releases, including TL2011, do not need you to `texhash` a local tree unless it's stored on a remote disk. So for most people simply adding files in the correct place inside `texmf` will be enough.